# How to Get the current date time while exexuing the exe which is created Using NSIS Installer?

Tags: nsis

My requirement is to create an installer that should print the current date and time... In my NSIS script I have used the following code to get the current date and time

```
 !define /date CUR_DATE "%m-%d-%Y %H-%M"
 MessageBox MB_OK "${CUR_DATE}"
```

I have compiled using NSIS complier and the out file is created. While I am executing the installer it displays the current date time as at what time the script file is compiled.. Not the current time of executing.... Whenever executes it print the same time.... But I want to get the current date time.. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.... The following in built command will help you to get the current time date time...

```
${GetTime} "" "L" $0 $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
```

$0 - Date $1 - Month $2 - Year $3 - Day $4 - Hour $5 - Minute $6 - Secs